# JS page to show animation while loading in background

Tags: javascript, animation, overlay

Perhaps there is an easy tweak to the below code, but my strength today is not in JS.  My website currently reloads index.php3 for various tasks.  These tasks require some significant database work and there is a visible delay while the database prepares the data for PHP to parse and present.  Therefore, I need a way to display a loading animation while the database is working and the PHP is parsing.  Below is what I have gleaned so far from the web and other bits...

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
</head>



<body onload="loadingAjax('myDiv');">

    <script>

    function loadingAjax(div_id)
    {
        $("#"+div_id).html('<center><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif"></center>');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php3",
            //data:         
            success: function(msg){
                $("#"+div_id).html(msg);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>


    <div id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

In essence, this page is loaded, and displays an animated gif, then when index.php3 is loaded, it should flip to show index.php3.  The problem is that it is not showing the website once it loads.

Thanks for the needle in my haystack, the help on stackoverflow is fantastic!

Comment: maybe it wasnt successful? (success doesnt get call in that event)

Comment: `<center>` tags...now those take me back.  :)

Comment: I watch the animation and it runs for a very short time then stops. It seems like it is triggering, but I don't know offhand how to prove it.

Comment: I do get this warning:  Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: Make use of the debugging tools available these days in your browser. Probably the most simple thing you can do is adding in `console.log` statements to watch the flow of your code.

Comment: ug, thank, learning something useful every day...I'll give it a whirl

Comment: I can confirm that msg has the correct html and php data in it... it's just not being displayed.

Comment: Yes, setting breakpoints in your browser developer tools can be quite useful too.  I would recommend against using the `success` callback, as it's deprecated.  Consider using the `.done()` method instead.  Also, it may be useful to chain a `.fail()` method so that you can log whether there's a bad response coming back from the index.php3 file.

Comment: Good point simianangel, can you give me a leg up on hos I would implement the .done() method in my code?

Comment: nevermind.. SimianAngel, I'll post it in a few mins when I get it sorted out... found the explantion

Comment: @Mark Might look gross in comments but I'll give it a whirl.  :)  `$.ajax({ // your parameters here }).done(function(response) { // do whatever you need to with the response from the server });`

Comment: I posted the updated code as an answer, same issues tho

Answer (score 0):

So, I updated the code here with the .done() method.

```
    function loadingAjax(div_id)
{
    $("#"+div_id).html('<center><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif"></center>');
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php3",
          //data:
        }).done(function(msg){        
         $("#"+div_id).html(msg);
         //console.log("msg = [ "+ msg + " ]");
        });
    console.log("end of function");
}
```

The only line inside the done function does not replace the div_id with the msg, or at least its not visible.

Comment: The code works if I replace the .html(msg) with .html("<h2>Hello World</h2>");  However, it needs to show the full index.php3.  It does flag the Synchronous XMLHttpRequest warning because there is a script buried behind index.php3 somewhere

Comment: Ah ha!  The error was breing caused by an old version of the google analytics tracking code.  I updated it to the latest and voila..it works.  Thanks for the help team!